# IE not showing footer and containe properly

Tags: html, css, sticky-footer

I am working on the following site: buzzspherefilms.site40.net and the footer is not showing as expected in IE. It works fine with Chrome and Mozilla but in IE, the footer is appearing at the bottom of the page. Can anyone see why? Also, any help on implementing this into a sticky footer would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Post related code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that you need to adjust the `margin-top` on `#container`.

In your layout, you have two fixed elements, `header` and `navbar`, with a combined height of 120px and 40px respectively.

If you set `margin-top: 160px` on `container`, the layout will work consistently across the browsers.

IE calculates the auto top margin differently than the other browsers, which can cause problems.

As for sticky-footers, there are articles on the web on how to do it, so that would be your first step.

**jQuery Fix**

You are trying to set the `container` height dynamically using jQuery.  The cross-browser issue arises probably because `.outerHeight` does the math differently in IE.

Comment this out first (you can put it back in later) and try a simple CSS fix.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
       $("#quickSearch").autocomplete({
       source: "quickSearch.php",
       minLength: 2
       });
          $('#container').css('marginTop', $('#header').outerHeight(true) + $('#navbar').outerHeight(true) );

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Hi Marc, this didn't fix it in IE.

Comment: Let me double check, what version of IE are you using and what DOCTYPE?

Comment: Give me a few minutes and I will build a quick fiddle to illustrate, might be helpful to others.

Comment: Thanks Marc. It's IE9 and the DOCTYPE is >> PUBLIC  XHTML 1.0 Transitional

Comment: I did not see the jQuery script, this is part of the issue.  Please see comment.  Do you want the page to scroll beneath the header/navbar elements?

Comment: Yes, that sorted it Marc :) Many thanks.

Comment: Just be careful with IE, it treats the CSS box model a bit differently than most other browsers. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You mention using sticky-footer but it doesn't look like you are using it. Here is the css that allows you to do it. (I just copy and pasted from the site)

```
* {
    margin: 0;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -142px; /* the bottom margin is the negative value of the footer's height */
}
.footer, .push {
height: 142px; /* .push must be the same height as .footer */
}
```

src: http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/